# How to make my sparql query with regex faster?

Tags: regex, performance, sparql, dbpedia

I have build a sparql query for dbpedia with a regex in it which is very slow :

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?label where {
    ?s rdfs:label ?label.
    ?s dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?photo.
    ?s dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
    FILTER langMatches( lang(?label), "FR" ).
    FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), "FR" ).
    FILTER regex(?label, "^Jules V", "i").

}
LIMIT 10
```

You can try it using the public endpoint http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql and see you have to wait some seconds.

Is there a way for me to get better performance on this, even if the final quality is not so good ?

Thanks,
Samuel

Comment: Have you determined the slow bit or are you just *guessing* that it might be the regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any query using `REGEX` will almost certainly be slow unless your query restricts to a small enough portion of the dataset.  Processing a `REGEX` basically requires that the store do a linear scan over the potential results checking each to see whether it matches the regular expression.

If you have a sufficiently simple regular expression as in your case you should try one of two things:

#### Solution 1 - Use a lighter weight string function

In your case you're looking for strings that start with a certain substring, so it will almost certainly be more efficient to use the `STRSTARTS` function instead since that doesn't require full regex.  This of course assumes your SPARQL engine complies with the latest SPARQL 1.1 draft specification.

#### Solution 2 - Use Full Text Search

Many stores include full text search extensions which can be used in place of `REGEX` and often yield significantly better performance because you are accessing a full text index rather than doing a linear scan over the potential results.

In the case of DBPedia the Virtuoso store behind it supports the following syntax:

```
?label bif:contains "Jules"
```

Note that the Virtuoso full text syntax is somewhat limited so you can't use `Jules V` as is because each term must be at least 4 characters (possibly 3).  But you can combine this with a further `FILTER` to narrow down to the results you wanted like so:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?label where {
    ?s rdfs:label ?label.
    ?s dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?photo.
    ?s dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
    FILTER langMatches( lang(?label), "FR" ).
    FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), "FR" ).
    ?label bif:contains "Jules" .
    FILTER (CONTAINS(?label, "V"))

}
LIMIT 10
```

This query runs almost instantaneously